# How to store Arraylist data in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to write `Arraylist<String>` to  postgresql. but getting below error.

```
ERROR: column "data" is of type character varying[] but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

If someone knows which data type i should use for column to store arraylist content in postgresql?

Thanks

Comment: You can define the column as bytea datatype

Comment: hey, in that case column value showing as`[binary data]`. still not able to see content

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JPA, Spring Data?

Have you looked up for `@ElementCollection`? I think it's gonna be helpful.

[Java JPA ElementCollection Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).